# Samba External SSD Share windows but cannot write to SSD from windows 10

Tags: mount, partition, raspberry-pi, samba, fstab

have built a rasbian pi3 and added an external SSD.

i have installed Samba to share SSD disk, wrote fstab $UUID=B260-EA42 /media/SSD vfat users,defaults 0 0

first problem is i cant login with user to samba only guest i can log in.

second one i cant add or delete any file folders in ssd.

Windows error screen shot:

[image: windows error screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done this already, try creating a samba user first, then allowing access to the directory for this user:

```
smbpasswd -a UserName
```

then:

```
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and make sure that you have the following lines in your config:

```
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
valid users = root
```

like this:

```
[Photos]
  comment = Photos
  path = /drives/Photos
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  guest ok = no
  valid users = root
```

Hope that was enough to solve your problem.